# Drag an element within text block

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, polymer

I can't find a way to drag an inline-block element, for example a **span** styled as inline-block, or indeed any inline-block element inside a block of text held within say, a **p** block.  I'm actually trying to drag and drop a custom **polymer2** element inside the text block.

For example:

I have the following...

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
```

and I want to click and drag an element located somewhere on the page, or even within the **p** block itself into the paragraph and drop it at any point within it.  So I'd either need a caret indicating the drop area or even better, flow the text around the hovering element.

Please note:
1) It does not have to be a **p** tag.  It could just as well be a **div** or even direct into the **body**

2) I do **not** wish to wrap the individual words within the paragraph in  tags so that they can be programatically flowed out of the way.

So, simply put, can an inline-block element be dropped into a text block?

It's kind of possible by making the block **contentEditable** but it only seems to copy the inline text of the element and not the element itself.  So that is of no use to me.

Note:
I'm more than happy to use a very lightweight framework to achieve this.